# What point meaning in the permission string lrwxrwxrwx.?

Tags: permissions

When I run an ls -la /, some files/folders it gives output like:

-rw-r-----**.**   1 root root         0 Jan 18  2020 1

drwxrwx---**.**   3 root root      4096 May 24  2016 ade

lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root         7 Feb 27  2018 bin -> usr/bin

So, what is the meaning the point (.) at the end in the permisions?

-rw-r-----**.**

drwxrwx---**.**

lrwxrwxrwx.

I thank in advance who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it indicates there is SElinux [security-enhanced-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) is present. Read this [file system permissions and notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions#Symbolic_notation) to better yourself on

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Pleasure all min